# What webcam apps are available and how to check if your webcam is working?

Tags: software-recommendation, webcam

What software is available for using webcams or ways of checking if my webcam is working correctly after installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## [Cheese](http://projects.gnome.org/cheese/) [image: Install Cheese]

[image]

> Cheese uses your webcam to take photos
> and videos, applies fancy special
> effects and lets you share the fun
> with others. It was written as part of
> Google's 2007 Summer of Code lead by
> daniel g. siegel and mentored by
> Raphaël Slinckx. Under the hood,
> Cheese uses GStreamer to apply fancy
> effects to photos and videos. With
> Cheese it is easy to take photos of
> you, your friends, pets or whatever
> you want and share them with others.

Comment: Note that this is not the best solution to test if the webcam works because, in my case and from lots of Ubuntu or Mint forums, you can have "no device found" with Cheese while the webcam will work with Guvcview. So to test the hardware and the driver the order of testing should be: 1-Gucvview, 2-Cheese, ... and, far behind, Skype where, using the webcam, obviously needs much more efforts to setup!

Answer (score 23):

**VLC** can be used for the given purpose.

*Media - Open capture device...*

[image]

Click drop-down menu for *Device selection - Video device name*.

When something like`/dev/video0` appears, just click Enter.

[image]

Then Play.

One can also launch directly the VLC webcam.

Save the playlist as the VLC webcam is running. *Media - Save playlist to file...* (e.g. save as `vlc-webcam.xspf` playlist file). Starting that playlist file in VLC will start the webcam.

Then one may create a desktop file for the same purpose; it should be similar to this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=VLC Webcam 
Comment=Webcam vlc 
Exec=vlc /path/to/vlc-webcam.xspf
Icon=/add/some/image/png/file.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=AudioVideo;Player;Recorder;
```

Make it executable. If you copy that into `/usr/share/applications` it will be searched and launched directly as any other application. In Synapse:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

**`ffplay` from ffmpeg**

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
ffplay /dev/video0
```

See also: [How to check available webcams from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348838/how-to-check-available-webcams-from-the-command-line/848390#848390)

Tested in Ubuntu 19.10.

[image]

Comment: Will this also work with usb microscopes as well. I guess microscopes are just fancy cameras with lens? I am planning to buy one from eBay but the cd it comes with supports only windows platform so was wondering if I could use ffmpeg

Comment: @user0193 what's the microscope model? It might be impossible to determine compabitility if the manufacturer does not give enough information. Image information could be sent in a number of non-standard obscure ways and decoded by an equally obscure decoder. But there's a chance. Worse case someone has to reverse engineer the thing. What are you planning on doing with it BTW?

Comment: Its one of those lowcost generic model found in [Ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/312322712865?hash=item48b7e26521:g:ymkAAOSwZtRb2nCH&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA8I8MZKI%2F%2FIMMqUMpCIAZMdVYOw6EK%2B%2BQjWeLuTli%2FGniGh69cLfV%2FxcMefJevGVlx0pXKezeJ1Q21ohO6ItgEoQXxxvgZ6a9rOYtBRR7sQblhdb2Fg%2BIf7HHN9Hzp88t7iHMBfRkjLcA0XKxVLiKifuEaI1CtnAyfcuCTc0KBhQYBnYzeBzM8uzYyRxNMbPSy0cPkxl1thQe%2FRgtXrBghzHneapXqx3cKAqDgk%2Bfahdac3BaWB6zwab3kh4AdZBX9NMTEVnaS2CIjdXtcR0ljnSAVFrvz0HK9EqU4Edj0eqaO3l6WGC7M8E59vmM%2FuvVLA%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR9a617uvYQ). I want to use it for soldering, so dont wanna spend much.

Answer (score 9):

## [Mousetrap](http://packages.ubuntu.com/mousetrap) [image: Install mousetrap]

### What is MouseTrap?

Mousetrap is a standalone GNOME application that allows users with physical impairments to move a mouse cursor. It uses a webcam to track the motion of any object visible by the camera and moves the mouse cursor according to the path of the tracked object (a user's head, for example). Distributed with software that allows accessible mouse clicking, MouseTrap will give most physically impaired users access to the full functionality of a mouse. Our ultimate goal is to have a usable, stable solution that allows users to control their cursors just as well as someone using a mouse.
MouseTrap is written in Python, based on the OpenCV library and uses image processing to translate the user's head movements into mouse events (movements, clicks) which allow users to interact with the different desktops managers and applications.

### How does it work?

[image: im2]

### Youtube demo video

http://www.youtube.com/profile?user=flaper87#grid/uploads

Answer (score 8):

## [Guvcview](http://packages.ubuntu.com/guvcview) [image: Install Guvcview]

**Description** - Simple GTK+ interface for capturing and viewing video from
devices supported by the Linux UVC driver.

### Features

**Video Recording** - Yes
**Image Capture** - Yes
**Video/Image Effects** - Yes
**Send Video/Image Remotely** - No
**Save in Different Formats** - Yes
**Options to Change Video/Image Properties** - Yes
**GUI Based** - Yes
**Note** - May need to run the app from terminal to change the device location. By default it reads `/dev/video0`. If webcam is on video1 you will need to run it like this: `guvcview -d /dev/video1`.

Comment: I have Logitech c920 and I get maximum 15 FPS on this software. Not very good.

Answer (score 3):

**QtCAM**

**Description** - QtCAM is free, Open Source Linux Web Camera Software with more than 10 image control settings, extension settings and Color space switching. Users could connect up to 6 cameras and stream videos simultaneously. It would also work with any V4L2 compatible device.

**Features**
**Video Recording** - Yes

**Image Capture** - Yes

**Video/Image Effects** - Yes

**Send Video/Image Remotely** - No

**Save in Different Formats** - Yes

**Options to Change Video/Image Properties** - Yes

**GUI Based** - Yes

Answer (score 2):

## [Kamerka](http://packages.ubuntu.com/kamerka) [image: Install Kamerka]

**Description** - KDE application which uses Video4Linux to get image from
webcam, with ability to save photos. It features easy to use, animated
and well-integrated user interface.

### Features

**Video Recording** - No
**Image Capture** - Yes
**Video/Image Effects** - No
**Send Video/Image Remotely** - No
**Save in Different Formats** - No
**Options to Change Video/Image Properties** - No
**GUI Based** - Yes

Answer (score 2):

## [Empathy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/empathy) [image: Install Empathy]

**Description** - Chat Client with many features including Audio/Video Chat, Chat logging and history and a lot of other stuff. Mentioned here mainly because of an easy and fast way of testing the webcam.

### Features

**Video Recording** - No
**Image Capture** - No
**Video/Image Effects** - No
**Send Video/Image Remotely** - No
**Save in Different Formats** - No
**Options to Change Video/Image Properties** - Yes
**GUI Based** - Yes
**Note** - Shown here because it is an easy option to check if Webcam works.

Answer (score 2):

### **Skype** ([Skype Website](http://www.skype.com/))

**Description** - VoIP App that can be used to check Audio/Video features of a webcam (Aside from the rest of the long description about what Skype obviously is and does ;) ).

### Features

**Video Recording** - No
**Image Capture** - No
**Video/Image Effects** - No
**Send Video/Image Remotely** - No
**Save in Different Formats** - No
**Options to Change Video/Image Properties** - Yes
**GUI Based** - Yes
**Note** - Shown here because it is an easy option to check if Webcam works. Not the first one I would actually recommend but hey, it's an option.

Answer (score 2):

https://webcamtests.com/

https://webcamtests.com/

**Description** - Website to test if a webcam is working. Can be used through Firefox, Chromium or Chrome (Or any other Browser found in Ubuntu that supports Flash Player)

### Features

**Video Recording** - No
**Image Capture** - No
**Video/Image Effects** - No
**Send Video/Image Remotely** - No
**Save in Different Formats** - No
**Options to Change Video/Image Properties** - Yes
**GUI Based** - Yes (Web Based / Flash PLayer Based)
**Note** - Shown here because it is an easy option to check if Webcam works. Ubuntu installs the needed drivers automatically. There is no need to install them for 99% of all webcams.

Comment: Website appears to be off line.

Comment: @FUZxxl Test again. Updated the site.

Answer (score 1):

## [Kamoso](http://packages.ubuntu.com/kamoso) [image: Install Kamoso]

**Description** - Utility that does the very simple actions a webcam offers,
like taking pictures or recording videos and adds some extra features that will
make the webcam usage both funnier and more useful.

### Features

**Video Recording** - Yes
**Image Capture** - Yes
**Video/Image Effects** - No
**Send Video/Image Remotely** - No
**Save in Different Formats** - No
**Options to Change Video/Image Properties** - Yes
**GUI Based** - Yes

Answer (score 1):

## [FSWebcam](http://packages.ubuntu.com/fswebcam) [image: Install FSWebcam]

**Description** - Tiny and flexible webcam command-line program for capturing
images from a V4L1/V4L2 device. It accepts a number of formats, can skip
the first (possibly bad) frames before performing the actual capture, and
can perform simple manipulation on the captured image, such as resizing,
averaging multiple frames or overlaying a caption or an image.

### Features

**Video Recording** - No
**Image Capture** - Yes
**Video/Image Effects** - No
**Send Video/Image Remotely** - No
**Save in Different Formats** - Yes (PNG and JPG)
**Options to Change Video/Image Properties** - Yes (Via command line options)
**GUI Based** - No
**Note** - Using it is as simple as `fswebcam -d /dev/video1 image.png` where `/dev/video1` is your webcam source and `image.png` is the name of the image file to save to.

Answer (score 0):

## [Webcam](http://packages.ubuntu.com/webcam) [image: Install Webcam]

**Description** - Utility that captures images from a
video4linux device such as bttv, annotates them and uploads them to a
webserver in an endless loop using FTP or SSH.

### **Features**

**Video Recording** - No
**Image Capture** - Yes
**Video/Image Effects** - No
**Send Video/Image Remotely** - Yes
**Save in Different Formats** - No (JPG Only)
**Options to Change Video/Image Properties** - Yes
**GUI Based** - No

Answer (score 0):

## [Camorama](http://packages.ubuntu.com/camorama) [image: Install Camorama]

**Description** - Utility to view and save images from a webcam
or any other Video4Linux device. It can apply a number of image filters and
make remote captures.

### Features

**Video Recording** - No
**Image Capture** - Yes
**Video/Image Effects** - Yes
**Send Video/Image Remotely** - Yes
**Save in Different Formats** - Yes
**Options to Change Video/Image Properties** - Yes
**GUI Based** - Yes
**Note** - May need to run the app from terminal to change the device location. By default it reads `/dev/video0`. If webcam is on video1 you will need to run it like this: `camorama -d /dev/video1`.

Answer (score 0):

## [CamGrab](http://packages.ubuntu.com/camgrab) [image: Install CamGrab]

**Description** - Tool meant to be used from shell scripts, etc, for grabbing a
single image from a Webcam. It comes with a simple shellscript which will produce a timestamped JPG for use as a webcam.

### Features

**Video Recording** - No
**Image Capture** - Yes
**Video/Image Effects** - No
**Send Video/Image Remotely** - No
**Save in Different Formats** - No
**Options to Change Video/Image Properties** - No
**GUI Based** - No

Answer (score 0):

## [Motion](http://packages.ubuntu.com/motion) [image: Install Motion]

**Description** - Program that monitors the video signal from
one or more cameras and is able to detect if a significant
part of the picture has changed. Or in other words, it can
detect motion. It is a command line based tool. It has no graphical
user interface. Everything is setup either via the
command line or via configuration files.

### Features

**Video Recording** - Yes
**Image Capture** - Yes
**Video/Image Effects** - No
**Send Video/Image Remotely** - Yes
**Save in Different Formats** - Yes (JPG and PPM)
**Options to Change Video/Image Properties** - Yes
**GUI Based** - No
**Note** - How to use it can be found in [How to make a Stop Motion or Time-lapse video with webcam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50339/how-to-make-a-stop-motion-or-time-lapse-video-with-webcam/33802#33802)

Answer (score 0):

## [Luvcview](http://packages.ubuntu.com/luvcview) [image: Install Luvcview]

**Description** - Camera viewer for UVC based webcams. It includes an mjpeg
decoder and is able to save the video stream as an AVI file.

### Features

**Video Recording** - Yes
**Image Capture** - Yes
**Video/Image Effects** - Yes
**Send Video/Image Remotely** - No
**Save in Different Formats** - Yes
**Options to Change Video/Image Properties** - Yes
**GUI Based** - Yes

Answer (score 0):

### **Google Video/Audio Plugin** ([Google Hangout](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/hangoutplugin))

**Description** - Google Plugin used for Video and Audio conferences (Eg: Gmail Chat or Google Hangout).

### Features

**Video Recording** - Yes
**Image Capture** - Yes
**Video/Image Effects** - Yes
**Send Video/Image Remotely** - Yes
**Save in Different Formats** - Yes
**Options to Change Video/Image Properties** - Yes
**GUI Based** - Yes (Web based)
**Note** - Shown here because it is an easy option to check if Webcam works. Ubuntu installs the needed drivers automatically. There is no need to install them for 99% of all webcams.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.test-cam.com

**Description** - Websites to test if a webcam is working. Can be used through Firefox, Chromium or Chrome (Or any other Browser found in Ubuntu that supports Flash Player)

Answer (score 0):

https://meet.google.com

Or any web meeting or conference website will help you check whether webcam and microphone is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

### [Webcam Recorder](https://addons.mozilla.org/ro/firefox/addon/webcam-recorder/)

**Description** - Record video from your computer's camera and/or record audio from your microphone

It is a firefox addon. The file size is 68,12 KB. This is a solution to check if your webcam is working.