# Want to know why Webcam can't be captured by Cheese while VLC picks it up

Tags: video, devices, stream

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as a guest on OSX VirtualBox, and enabled the builtin webcam on Macbook.

While I thought the webcam wasn't working because `sudo cheese` command wasn't picking up anything except for `assertion fail: device != NULL` log, trying something with VLC(`vlc v4l2:///dev/video0`) properly picked up webcam and worked.

I want to know why VLC works but Cheese doesn't, but can't figure out what to look for. I looked up this [SO post](https://askubuntu.com/a/582000/894779) insisting that cheese has some issues, but that post didn't make clear what issues that can cause Cheese not to pick up stream properly .

Comment: I have exactly this same problem.  I'm curious to know what else you've done here...  It just doesn't make sense that you can get to the camera, but you can't get to the camera.