# How do I take pictures with asus 1015cx?

Tags: camera

I wanted to use my computer to take a picture but could not figure out how to access camera thanks.

Comment: Try using program cheese. Install it with: sudo apt-get install cheese

Comment: possible duplicate of [Webcam Apps and ways of checking if Webcam is working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48245/webcam-apps-and-ways-of-checking-if-webcam-is-working) (We closed [that](http://askubuntu.com/questions/168839/what-program-i-can-uses-to-take-a-picture-using-my-laptop-integrated-camera) as a duplicate of it, no reason not to close this, too. It contains all the necessary information.)

Answer (score 2):

[Webcam](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Webcam)? Checkout Cheese via `sudo apt-get install cheese`.