# How to install Kazam 1.5.3?

Tags: webcam, screencast, kazam

Months ago, I used to install Kazam 1.5.3 using these commands :

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kazam-team/unstable-series
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install kazam python3-cairo python3-xlib
```

Them main reason I want Kazam 1.5.3 exactly is because it comes with a webcam option.

But now, when I execute the previous commands, it only installs the previous version (Kazam 1.4), which doesn't come with a webcam option.

Is there a way to get the latest version?

Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Kazam is available in the official Ubuntu repositories, but it's an old version (1.4) and `ppa:kazam-team/unstable-series` has not been updated for 16.04 (and does not include debian [patches](https://alioth.debian.org/scm/loggerhead/collab-maint/kazam/unstable/files/head:/debian/patches/)).

You can install Kazam 1.5.4 from my own ppa (it provides the debian packages up to **21.04**):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:sylvain-pineau/kazam
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kazam
```

[image]

Comment: webcam is just black :(

Comment: Thanks @sylvain for your answer.  I'm on `Ubuntu 16.10 LTS` and these commands do not work for me. Any thoughts. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 I've updated the ppa, the new packages are available for Y and Z.

Comment: Thanks @SylvainPineau for your help. Now it works like a charm.  Thanks again.

Comment: webcam is black for me as well.  @FelipeMicaroniLalli did u solve this?

Comment: Just uploaded a new version for 20.04. The old ppa copy that I did never really worked. Please install `kazam` (1.5.4-0ubuntu6) from the same ppa

Comment: @sylvain anything for 20.10 ?

Comment: Thanks Sylvain but it looks like there is a dependency not listed in the package causing some issues, FYI https://askubuntu.com/a/1207425/300877

Comment: Thanks for the notification, fixed via `kazam - 1.5.4-0ubuntu7 ` (20.04)

Comment: @akikara I've copied the 20.04 ppa version up to Impish

Comment: Great news @SylvainPineau any progress for 20.10? Already checked. Nice work!

Answer (score 3):

cd to `/etc/apt/sources.d/` open up the `kazam.list` file and make sure you change repo to devel.

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d# ls
kazam-team-ubuntu-unstable-series-xenial.list  kazam-team-ubuntu-unstable-   series-xenial.list.save

/etc/apt/sources.list.d# cat kazam-team-ubuntu-unstable-series-xenial.list
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kazam-team/unstable-series/ubuntu devel main
```

Answer (score 1):

Install using PIP/PIP3

> pip install kazam==1.5.6 distutils-extra-python

These versions are available and has same features as 1.5.3

[image]

Comment: Question was how to install 1.5.3 how is this an answer to that? Add some more details it may make sense then.

Comment: WARNING Kazam - Failed to correctly detect operating system on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS + 6.2.9-060209-generic