# Installing Kazam 1.5.3 on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: screen, webcam, 16.10, kazam

I wonder how to install Kazam 1.5.3 on Ubuntu 16.10. I tried the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install kazam
```

This command installs Kazam 1.4.5, however I need the version which has the option of "Screen recorder + webcam". Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Might sound a bit pedantic,  but Ubuntu 16.10 is not an LTS(Long term support) release. So it will be end of life in 9 months.

Comment: If installing 14.04 instead of 16.10 is an option, that would be best, as the Kazam PPA only provides packages for 14.04. Otherwise, you could try installing those packages on 16.10, but it could cause issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Kazam 1.5.3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766440/how-to-install-kazam-1-5-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it working, using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:sylvain-pineau/kazam
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kazam
```

Comment: This is a ppa hosted by an individual. Originally posted here https://askubuntu.com/a/789812/309358.  Provide the link at least

Comment: On my system, this still installs 1.4.5 and not 1.5.3

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below commands i have sucessfully installed

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kazam-team/unstable-series
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kazam python3-cairo python3-xlib
```

Thanks
suresh

Comment: Thanks @suresh for your answer. Are you sure that these commands install `Kazam 1.5.3`? On my machine  with `Ubuntu 16.10 LTS`, these commands install  `Kazam 1.4.5-2`.

Comment: You can check available versions via `apt-cache policy PACKAGENAME`

Comment: This PPA does not provide packages for Yakkety.

Comment: yes using above commands you will get installed kazam 1.5.3

Comment: This is unstable series ppa provided by kazam build team. It installs the current unstable version (going on in production) not necessarily 1.5.3

Comment: On my system it installs kazam 1.4.5 and not 1.5.3