# ImportError: cannot import name GUdev, introspection typelib not found

Tags: python, kazam

Can anyone suggest how I fix up the errors from standard application of Kazam screenshot app:

```
alistair@alsE590:~$ kazam
/usr/bin/kazam:77: DeprecationWarning: dist() and linux_distribution() functions are deprecated in Python 3.5
  dist = platform.linux_distribution()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/kazam", line 148, in <module>
    from kazam.app import KazamApp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kazam/app.py", line 36, in <module>
    from kazam.backend.prefs import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kazam/backend/prefs.py", line 30, in <module>
    from kazam.backend.webcam import Webcam
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kazam/backend/webcam.py", line 24, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GObject, GUdev
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 133, in load_module
    'introspection typelib not found' % namespace)
ImportError: cannot import name GUdev, introspection typelib not found
```

Comment: Have you figured it out? Same thing

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error on Ubuntu 20 Lts

I installed kazam using ppa:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:sylvain-pineau/kazam
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kazam
```

To fix it - uninstall kazam, ppa-reposotiroy, and install kazam from the standard Ubuntu repo:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove kazam
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:sylvain-pineau/kazam
sudo apt-get install kazam
```

Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the package `gir1.2-gudev-1.0`.

Comment: sadly it has more errors:  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 655, in add_section
    raise ValueError('Invalid section name: %r' % section)
ValueError: Invalid section name: 'DEFAULT'

Comment: That's what I'm still getting. I think that once an official release comes out it's going to suck just like on everything else in 20.04

Comment: That works! Someone should tell Sylvain

Comment: @JeffTrull thanks for the notification. `kazam - 1.5.4-0ubuntu7 ` has been pushed to the ppa with the new dependency.