# On Ubuntu 18.04 can I hide the title bar AND still see the close/minimize/maximize icons?

Tags: gnome, titlebar

This is for all programs not just Firefox.  I would like 18.04 to behave a bit more like Unity.

Comment: Do you mean **any** window of an application or **only maximised** windows of an application? First one is not easily doable without modifying the source-code of the application (the feature for Firefox was implemented by Firefox developers themselves). Second one should be possible, see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966685/wasted-screen-space-due-to-multiple-horizontal-bars-at-the-top-when-an-applicati

Comment: Don't mind, only maximised would work for me just fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wasted screen space due to multiple horizontal bars at the top when an application is open in GNOME desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966685/wasted-screen-space-due-to-multiple-horizontal-bars-at-the-top-when-an-applicati)

Comment: I would say you should now follow this answer as the other one didn't work for me.

Comment: By the way in the other answer the user went back to Unity!  I feel his pain but I want to try and stay as close to standard current support Ubuntu as possible.

Comment: No, thanks! I don't prefer installing GNOME extensions system-wide as the root :) Also most probably you're doing something wrong, works fine here with 18.04. Perhaps consider expanding the "*didn't work for me*" part so that we can analyse what's going wrong.

Comment: For Ubuntu 19.04 you can use [Unite Gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The supported way to achieve such effect would be to install the Gnome Shell extension Pixelsaver straight from the software center. You can install it with the following command:

`sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-pixelsaver`

You may need to enable the extension using the tool "Extensions" (only in Ubuntu 20.04 and higher) or using "Gnome Tweaks". You can install Gnome Tweaks from the software center, or install it with the command:

`sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

An unsupported way to install gnome Shell extensions is by using the [Gnome Extensions website](https://extensions.gnome.org/). To enable this, you need [some preparations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions). You will also find Pixel Saver there, but the extension [Unite](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/) appears to be better maintained.

*Caveat*: these extensions may only work when your desktop is running on the Xorg graphics system. Ubuntu 18.04 by default will run on Xorg. However, by default, Ubuntu 17.10 used Wayland. You can switch between using Xorg or Wayland using the cog on the log in screen.

Comment: sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-pixelsaver
didn't work, it seem to install OK but no change to the title bar.  Thanks.


Installing via the software center worked perfectly and gave me back some screen real estate.

Comment: If anyone else wants to do the same thing, then I would recommend you also install gnome tweaks from the Ubuntu Software center; as it then gives you a convenient way to turn extensions on and off.

Comment: @Terry Installing via software center is equivalent to the install command. However, through Software center the extension is perhaps enabled automatically, but not when using the command line. I will add the advice to have Tweaks installed, thanks!

Comment: sound right to me, in fact that was the conclusion I came to.

Comment: In addition, I had to restart the machine for the change to take effect.(Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: @BinodKalathil no need. At most, you need to log out and back in (or restart Gnome Shell).