# How can I remove the title bar on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: gnome, 19.04, titlebar

I've tried the following shell extensions:

- pixel-saver
- Unite
- No Title bar
- Gnome Global Application Menu (HUD Gnome)

but none of them work on Ubuntu 19.04 and the title bar is really annoying. Are there any solutions that i could remove it or merge it with top bar?

I've looked through

- [Wasted screen space due to multiple horizontal bars at the top when an application is open in GNOME desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966685/wasted-screen-space-due-to-multiple-horizontal-bars-at-the-top-when-an-applicati)
- [Ubuntu 17.10 windows' menu in panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966989/ubuntu-17-10-windows-menu-in-panel)
- [Hide maximized title bar in Ubuntu 18.04](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/10/hide-maximized-title-bar-ubuntu-18-04/)
- [On Ubuntu 18.04 can I hide the title bar AND still see the close/minimize/maximize icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075690/on-ubuntu-18-04-can-i-hide-the-title-bar-and-still-see-the-close-minimize-maximi)

and more with no luck.

[image]

Comment: This works for me (not removed but tiny): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257163/reduce-title-bar-height-in-gnome-3-gtk-3

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of titlebars, the "classical" title bar provided as a Windows decoration and, for GTK3 applications only, the new "Client side decorations" (CSD), where the title bar is provided by the application itself, and as such can contain other functional elements such as buttons etc.

All solutions you tried remove the "classical" title bar. They will work on 19.04 provided you run xorg, and may not necessarily work on Wayland. So first [check whether you are running xorg or wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904940/how-can-i-tell-if-i-am-running-wayland). If you are running Wayland, you can switch to xorg by logging out, then before logging back in, you can select a session on xorg after clicking the cog wheel.

If your application uses a CSD titlebar, then it cannot be removed.

Comment: So following [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/a/990224/618824) i get `x11` output and follwing [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/a/968772/618824) returns empty.. so I would assume i'm running `xorg`

And the title bar i am trying to remove exists on almost all the applications that i open and it's quite chunky therefor i don't think it CSD (E.g. it exist on Telegram and Termianl)

also i don't have cog wheel when i log out 

Thanks for response

Comment: At least the Unite extension is very well maintained, works up to Gnome Shell 3.32 (Ubuntu 19.04). It requires xorg, which is the standard display server in 18.04 and up (only 17.10 shipped with Wayland as default).

Comment: @vanadium I would say that your comment should be an answer as Unite does everything one might need. Works with 19.10 as well for me

Comment: @ThunderBiggi the OP used Unite, but additionally, the OP did not specify whether he wants to get rid of the title bar on maximized apps or on any window.

Comment: @vanadium is the latter even possible? I still think Unite is the closest they can get to an anwer, but ok.

Comment: @ThunderBiggi Yes, see link provided on comment on question

Comment: For those who wonder: Unite (which works for me too), can be installed simply by going there : https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/ and activating the button. Thanks @vanadium