# How can I access my webcam data?

Tags: webcam, video-recording

Can I get access to my webcam data, like a real digital recording system?

Comment: Link only answers are frowned on so here's a link only comment https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-motion-detection-webcam-ubuntu/  This works for clip capture and live streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Cheese](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/cheese) by clicking that link.

Then, open Cheese from the Dash. You can record and view a live video stream of your webcam.

P.S. You can also do this through VLC! Check https://askubuntu.com/a/614654/423626

Comment: I enjoyed the software but i was looking for something more of a Live Streaming Webcam and not just a simple take photo/record video.

Comment: Try this: http://xmodulo.com/live-stream-video-webcam-linux.html